# Sending email to registered members without repetation

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send emails to registered users in a website, the script works fine, but there is one problem, it repeat sending the emails.

For example: we have 3 registered users in the database (Mysql), the PHP script, first, selects the email address, then it sends the message to it.

The problem comes here:
1- It selects email 1 and send the message to it (Create!). 
2- It selects email 2 beside email 1 and, then, it sends the message to both of them.
3- It selects email 3 and send the message to the three emails (1,2 and 3).

Here is the code:

```
require 'Mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$limit=3;
$active="yes";
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select email,name from users where active=? limit ?');
$stmt->bind_param('si', $active,$limit);
$stmt->execute();
$i=0;
$stmt->bind_result($email,$name);
$arr = array();
while($stmt->fetch()) {
$row = array();
array_push($arr, $row);
include "compose_mail.php";}
```

The compose_mail.php

```
$mail->isSMTP();  
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';        // Set mailer      to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'The Host';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP      authentication
$mail->Username = 'username';       // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';       // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';         // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;            // TCP port to connect  to

$mail->From = 'email';
$mail->FromName = 'websit name';
$mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);        // Set email format to  HTML

$mail->Subject = $title;
$mail->Body    = '
The HTML message';

if(!$mail->send()) {} else {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop is doing some unwanted things:

```
$stmt->bind_result($email,$name);
$arr = array();
while($stmt->fetch()) {
$row = array();
array_push($arr, $row);
include "compose_mail.php";}
```

the include "compose_mail.php"; gets included every loop, so after 3 loops you have 3 includes of the compose_mail.php.

Include the compose_mail.php before the loop and change the compose_mail.php to have a function call in it:

```
function sendMail(your parameters) {
   Your mail code;
}
```

Then call this function in the while loop. THis has clean parameters every time and the repeated send should stop.

The total structure would become something like:

```
require 'Mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
include "compose_mail.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$limit=3;
$active="yes";
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select email,name from users where active=? limit ?');
$stmt->bind_param('si', $active,$limit);
$stmt->execute();
$i=0;
$stmt->bind_result($email,$name);

while($stmt->fetch()) {
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $arr = array();
  $row = array();
  array_push($arr, $row);
  sendMail($mail,$arr,$row);
}
```

That way all parameters are reset every loop, so multiple mail should be impossible.

Comment: Thank you so much Norbert for your answer, it sounds great, I will try it, and let you know the result.

Comment: I think I didn't get it well. I add the code above (in the compose_mail.php) in the function, and called that function in the while loop, the same problem occurred. In 3 loops I get 3 emails! What is your advice?

Comment: Norbert, I really appreciate your kindness, thank you so much for your help, it works now :)